# curve works for some object but not other

Tags: r, curve

I'm baffled why #1 would work while #2 wouldn't?

```
x=rnorm(100);curve(dnorm(x))

y=rnorm(100);curve(dnorm(y))
Error in curve(dnorm(y)) : 'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'
```

Comment: What part of "expression containing 'x'" is unclear? Do you see an "x" in the expression given to the second call to `curve`?

Comment: Also, run `curve(dnorm(x))` on a clean session.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize functions and expressions must contain literal "x". I thought x means any general variable. It's clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `curve()` is somewhat magic and by default requires an expression **written as a function of x** (literally): from `?curve`.

> expr: The name of a function, or a call or an expression written as
>             a function of ‘x’ which will evaluate to an object of the
>             same length as ‘x’.

You could use

```
curve(dnorm(y),xname="y")
```

I have to warn you that the `x` and `y` values you are defining via `rnorm()` in your code are being ignored completely.  (You could edit your question to explain better what you're trying to do ...)

Comment: Thank you. It's clear now. Your warning is great too. I didn't think of this subtle point as curve in this case just take 101 values between 0 and 1 and generate the y values. Theses values have nothing to do with the values defined outside curve.